# How to change the background color in Google script editor

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, ide, themes

I wonder is it possible now to change theme in script editor from white to dark background. If not how to make Google make it.

Comment: You should add more tags to your question, or nobody will see it.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Google Chrome, you can add the [AppsScript Color extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appsscript-color/ciggahcpieccaejjdpkllokejakhkome).  It has two dark color schemes to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

The new Apps Script IDE in 2021 has a built-in 'high contrast mode' which makes the editor background black.

To enable: Press F1 > search for High Contrast Theme

Source: https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/#highContrastTheme (some other great tips in there too)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to set chrome to use auto dark mode.
chrome://flags (or edge://flags)
'Auto Dark Mode for Web Contents' - There are a couple options. I prefer 'Enabled with increased text contrast'

It's a good middle ground between [AppScript Color Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appsscript-color/ciggahcpieccaejjdpkllokejakhkome)'s Dracula (not enough contrast) and Monokai (too much contrast) options. It affects ALL WEB PAGES though.

Answer (score 0):

It's the "use high contrast mode" in the settings on a Chromebook. Otherwise try [the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the code editor -> click inspect -> find the element that contains the code -> find css background -> add property `background-color:#ccc;` or whatever color you want -> done -> works every browser

Comment: but you have to do it everytime you refresh

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use our free extension that adds color schemes and search functionality to the new Monaco editor https://www.swroot.com/black-script